# Referencing view-model of element using Aurelia's ref attribute

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Aurelia provides the [`ref` attribute](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5) which among other things is supposed to be able to provide a reference to a custom element's view-model.

I'm trying to construct an example where the value of one textbox (producer) is piped to another readonly textbox (consumer).

As expected:

- Typing into the producer textbox calls `producerInput`, setting the new value.
- `producerOutput` is polled repeatedly since the binding to `consumerInput` should be updated.
- `consumerOutput` is polled repeatedly since the binding to the consumer textbox should be update.

However `consumerInput` is not getting called. If I understand things correctly it should get called after each call to `producerOutput`. `consumerInput` not getting called means that the value does not get piped to the consumer textbox. Why doesn't `consumerInput` get called and how do I fix it?

ref.html

```
<template>

    <require from="producer"></require>
    <require from="consumer"></require>

    <producer producer.ref="producerViewModel"></producer>
    <consumer consumerInput.bind="producerViewModel.producerOutput"></consumer>

</template>
```

ref.js

```
export class Ref {

}
```

producer.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        producer: <input value.bind="producerInput" />
    </div>
</template>
```

producer.js

```
import {customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('producer')
export class Producer {

    set producerInput(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    get producerOutput() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

consumer.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        consumer: <input value.bind="consumerOutput" readonly />
    </div>
</template>
```

consumer.js

```
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('consumer')
@bindable('consumerInput')
export class Consumer { 

    set consumerInput(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    get consumerOutput() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

**Updated working solution:**

ref.html:

```
<template>

    <require from="producer"></require>
    <require from="consumer"></require>

    <producer producer.ref="producerViewModel"></producer>
    <consumer input.bind="producerViewModel.output"></consumer>

</template>
```

ref.js

```
export class Ref {

}
```

producer.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        producer: <input value.bind="output" />
    </div>
</template>
```

producer.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Producer {

    @bindable output;

}
```

consumer.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        consumer: <input value.bind="input" readonly />
    </div>
</template>
```

consumer.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Consumer { 

    @bindable input;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the DOM automatically lower-cases all attributes.  You can't use `consumerInput` or `producerOutput` for a bindable property name.  Aurelia uses a convention that hyphenates bindable property names that have mixed casing.

For example, `class MyElement { @bindable fooBar }` would be used like this:

```html
<my-element foo-bar.bind="baz"></my-element>
```

try this:

```js
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('consumer')
export class Consumer { 
    @bindable input;

    inputChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
      // aurelia will call this automatically- a convention looks for methods on the vm that match bindable property names.
    }
}
```

similar changes would be needed for the producer custom element.